# Should the conditional operator evaluate all arguments?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, 64-bit

When writing this:

```
1: inline double f( double arg ) {
2:    return arg == 0.0 ? 0.0 : 1./arg;
3: }
4: const double d = f( 0.0 );
```

The microsoft visual studio 2005 64-bit compiler came with

```
line 4: warning C4723: potential divide by 0
```

While you and I can clearly see that a div-by-zero is *never* going to happen...

Or is it?

Comment: Take care, comparing "double" arguments on equality. Evil magic happens there...

Comment: No it doesn't. Perfectly well-defined process. In particular, `0.0 == -0.0`. Hence, for all sets of values for which `1./arg` is defined, we know that `arg != 0.0`.

Comment: @MSalters: But due to rounding errors, arg  might not be 0.0 (or -0.0 for that matter) when you expected it to.

Comment: It's not a bug as far as standards compliance is concerned. But that doesn't mean you can't submit a bug report to connect.microsoft.com. You're right that in this case, it might be reasonable to expect the compiler determine that the division by zero can never happen. Let Microsoft know then.

Comment: @jalf: True, it may not be zero due to rounding. But in that case, there's no divide by zero. The following two statements are entirely equivalent and interchangable: `x==0` and `1./x is a divsion by zero` (under IEE754 and all other implementations I know)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an obvious bug, beyond doubt.

The intent of the warning is NOT to warn about all divisions in a program. That would be far too noisy in any reasonable program. Instead, the intent is to warn you when you need to check an argument. In this case, you did check the argument. Hence, the compiler should have noted that, and shut up.

The technical implementation of such a feature is done by labelling variables in code branches with certain attributes. One of the most common attributes is the tri-state "Is null". Before the branch, `arg` is an external variable and `arg [[Isnull]]` is unknown. But after the check on `arg` there are two branches. In the first branch `arg [[Isnull]]` is true. In the second branch `arg [[Isnull]]` is false.

Now, when it comes to generating divide-by-zero and null pointer warnings, the `[[IsNull]` attribute should be checked. If true, you have a severe warning/error. If unknown, you should generate the warning shown above - a potential problem, beyond what the compiler can prove. But in this case, the `[[isNull]]` attribute is False. The compiler by the same formal logic as humans, knows that there is no risk.

But how do we know that the compiler is using such an `[[Isnull]]` attribute internally? Recall the first paragraph : without it, it would have to either warn always or never. We know it warns sometimes, ergo there must be an `[[IsNull]]` attribute.

Comment: That's solid reasoning.  I can live with that -especially since it proves my gut feeling.

Comment: A recent Linux bug was caused by exactly this attribute. In the offending code, a pointer was first dereferenced (basically `int* member = &(foo->bar);` and then checked `if (!foo) return;`. However, because of the dereference, the `foo[[IsNull]]` attribute was already set to false, and the NULL check optimized out.

Answer (score 11):

The compiler is not able to statically analyze all code paths and take into account all possibilities all the time. Theoretically, complete analysis of a program behavior just by looking into its source code can provide a solution to halting problem, which is undecidable. Compilers have a limited set of static analysis rules to detect rules. The C++ standard does not require the compiler to issue such kind of warnings, so, no. It's not a bug. It's more like a nonexistent feature.

Comment: You're right.  It can never be a bug from the C++ standard point of view, since it concerns warnings.

However, if this 'flaw' forces me to rewrite perfectly valid code (or surround it with `#pragma`s), from a 'computer program' point of view, it's a bug.

Comment: @xtofl: The key word in the warning is "potential"

Comment: Agreed, but the key pain is that we try to treat warnings as errors, and cannot do so with 'false positive' warnings.

Comment: @xtofl: You are using a tool. If it gives unneeded warnings, you will have to ignore them. It may be a "bug" for you, but it's the tool you are using and you cannot modify it.

Comment: @xtofl: you could #pragma warning(disable:4723)

Answer (score 7):

No, the conditional operator does not evaluate both arguments. However, a potential divide-by-zero, if a compiler can detect such a thing, is typically reported. It is not for nought that the standard takes up ~2 pages to describe the behavior of this operator.

From N-4411:

> **5.16 Conditional operator**
>
> **1** Conditional expressions group
> right-to-left. The first expression is
> contextually converted to bool (Clause
> 4). It is evaluated and if it is true,
> the result of the conditional
> expression is the value of the second
> expression, otherwise that of the
> third expression. Only one of the
> second and third expressions is
> evaluated. Every value computation and
> side effect associated with the first
> expression is sequenced before every
> value computation and side effect
> associated with the second or third
> expression.

Also, note:

> **3** Otherwise, if the second and third
> operand have different types, and
> either has (possibly cv-qualified)
> class type, an attempt is made to
> convert each of those operands to the
> type of the other.

The example you have cited has the same type for both the second and the third expressions -- rest assured, only the first will be evaluated.

Comment: I doubt point 3 actually says that both operands will be evaluated. I think this rather concerns whether things like `std::string s("A"); const char* c = "B"; std::string a = cond() ? s : c; const char* b = cond() ? s : c;` should compile or not (determining what the result type of the operator should be: the compiler checks what can be cast to what - in this case the first ?: compiles, since `const char*` can be implicitly converted to std::string, but the second doesn't compile, since the result type of the operator is `std::string`, and this can't be implicitly converted to `const char*`)

Answer (score 3):

the code for the division will be generated, hence the warning. but the branch will never be taken when `arg` is 0, so it is safe.

Answer (score 3):

operator== for floating-point numbers is unsafe (i.e. you cannot trust it, due to rounding issues).  In this specific case it is actually safe, so you can ignore the warning, but the compiler will not make such an analysis based on an operator whose results are somewhat unpredictable in the general case.

Answer (score 3):

The conditional operator shouldn't evaluate all arguments. But I believe you could take `arg` almost equal to 0, so `arg == 0.0` will be `false`, but `1./arg` will give "division by zero" result. So I think that warning is useful here.

By the way, Visual C++ 2008 doesn't give such warning.

Comment: IEEE 754 floating point divisions in C will not throw divide by zero. The result of dividing by zero will be +Infinity, -Infinity, or NaN

Comment: The result can be +Infinity or -Infinity for subnormal numbers, but I would call that an overflow rather than a division by zero.

Comment: @starblue: almost correct. `1./arg` cannot overflow. `10.0/arg` could overflow, though. (again assuming IEEE754, 1E0 / 2E-308 = 5E307 which is < 1.7E308)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other comments: the warning is generate by the compiler, the dead branch is removed by the optimizer which runs later - possibly even at link stage.

So no, it's not a bug. The warning is an additional service provided by the compiler, not mandated by the standard. It's an unfortunate side effect of the compiler / linker architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to avoid the warning using the Microsoft-specific `__assume` keyword. I'm not sure if you can tie it in with the conditional operator. Otherwise something like

```
if (arg == 0.0){
  return 0.0;
}
else {
__assume(arg != 0.0);
  return 1./arg;
}
```

may be worth a shot. Or, of course, just silence the warning during this function, with the appropriate `#pragma`.